# using dompdf in codeigniter not making pdfs on live

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

I am creating pdfs using this code

```
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents($this->config->item('file_path') . $pdf_name, $pdf);
$data['pdf'] = site_url('uploads/pdf/' . $pdf_name);
```

It works perfectly on XMPP localhost, but on LIVE server I get this error.

A PHP Error was encountered

```
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  file_put_contents(/home/xyz/public_html/abc/uploads/pdf/quotation_1502863603.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/Admin.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 742</p>
```

Please guide me what could be the issue on a LIVE server?

Comment: Did you already check this file `/home/xyz/public_html/abc/uploads/pdf/quotation_1502863603.pdf` exist on server when the function was called ?

Comment: No it has to be created dynamically. It is working fine on localhost.

Comment: Give write permission to `home/xyz/public_html/abc/uploads/pdf` directory

Comment: the error show that the file is not exist so I think it was not created. You need to check it again and check the permission of this folder

Comment: The folder already has 777 permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong in here `$this->config->item('file_path')` (path - `/home/xyz/public_html/abc/uploads/pdf/`). This path belongs to localhost and not to the server.

You should have try

```
$pdf_path = 'uploads/pdf/'.$pdf_name;
file_put_contents($pdf_path, $pdf);
```

Codeigniter Environment nothing to do with hosting path, its need an only relative path. *As well check permeation on upload path (777)*

Answer (score 0):

use terminal to check the path of the folder 
cd /home/xyz/public_html/abc/uploads/pdf/

in above command, folder is available then next check for permission (should be writable - 755)

Comment: The permission for `/home/xyz/public_html/abc/uploads/pdf/` is already `777`

Comment: try with chmod 755 /home/xyz/public_html/abc/uploads/pdf/

Comment: Still not working. If the file doesn't exists, file_put_contents create it automatically correct?

Comment: go inside pdf and ../pdf folder and check ls -l   for permission - whether its writable by apache or not.   Also  tail -f ~apache2/error.log and run your script to check apache error log